# Passing String through C# Code Behind to SQL in .ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

I am pretty new at working with this kind of thing so forgive me if my question seems too easy.  I have been trying for a while at this and have searched through every relevant article I can find but I cannot get my code to work.

I want to pass a string from 'BadgeNum.Text' through a parameter on the other side and have it execute a query.  I cannot get the value to pass correctly and thus cannot get any records to appear out of my query.  I have tested the query multiple times using the hard-coded data and it works fine.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Oracle1TestString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Oracle1TestString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT MODEL_NUMBER, SERIAL_NUMBER, DEFECT_CODE, RECORD_DATE, RECORD_TIME, PRODUCTION_DATE, AUDIT_TYPE FROM AUDITENT WHERE AUDITOR_BADGE = @BadgeNum" 
            onselecting="GridDataSource_Selecting">

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNum" Direction="Input" DbType="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the code behind (C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        BadgeNum.Text = "0205096";
        Parameter badge = new Parameter();
        badge.DefaultValue = BadgeNum.Text;
        badge.Type = TypeCode.String;
        badge.Name = "BadgeNum";
        GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(badge);
        GridDataSource.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then is your prefix possibly wrong in your select statement

```
@BadgeNum
```

vs

```
:BadgeNum
```

Comment: That change made the page crash completely with the following server error:

Exception Details: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Actually, I just got the same error by removing the <SelectParameters> section from above.  I think the value is actually getting through except that the Oracle DB is having a hard time handling it.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much.  You have no idea how much time I spent on this stupid little bug.

Comment: No problem, I didn't notice it was the oracle at first look

Comment: Actually, now that I got that working, I tried working in my string dates into the code.  It looks like this:
    WHERE AUDITOR_BADGE = :BadgeNum AND RECORD_DATE => TO_DATE(:StartDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND RECORD_DATE <= TO_DATE(:EndDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')

This caused an exception now too as well.

Comment: @se_brandon probably should post that as another question with details, tag it with oracle as well